# Проблема с публикацией игры в Google Play: Набор Android App Bundle подписан с помощью неправильного ключа

Tags: android, unity3d

Текст ошибки вот такой:

```
Набор Android App Bundle подписан с помощью неправильного ключа. Выберите правильный ключ и повторите попытку. Набор App Bundle должен быть подписан сертификатом с цифровым отпечатком
SHA1: ***
. Однако для загруженного набора App Bundle используется сертификат с цифровым отпечатком
SHA1: ***
```

Игра написана на Unity. Это релиз, а не обновление. Когда готовил игру к билду, в разделе Publishing Settings создал два ключа Project Keystore и Project Key. Alias ещё. Никак не пойму откуда могла взяться эта претензия. Что за "сертификат с цифровым отпечатком"?

Может всё дело в том, что я раньше уже публиковал одну игру, но написанную на Android Studio, Libgdx? Я нашёл тот ключ от той игры, применил его в своём новом проекте на Unity, забилдил - и всё-равно при создании рабочего выпуска в консоли плей гугла выходит эта ошибка.

Как разработчик я в Гугл Плей Консоль зарегистрировался в этом году, весной. И уже не помню, получал ли какой-то "сертификат с цифровым отпечатком", когда регистрировался. Но у меня привычка все ключи, пароли, всё важное сохранять. Ищу у себя и не нахожу ничего похожего на сертификат. Игры у меня всего две: та первая, опубликованная, и вот эта новая.

Comment: Тут читайте: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756

Comment: И всё же, для каждого отдельного проекта (игры, приложения и т.д.) эти ключи и сертификаты свои разные или у всех должен быть один и тот же?

Comment: Это как вы сам решите. Рекомендуется для каждого приложения новые генерить. Но ничего не запрещает и переиспользовать.